# Multiple timezone clocks in topbar on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, time, clock

I want to have several time zone clocks (cities with local time) in my top bar on my Ubuntu 20.04. There is a similar question and [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1268460/1659300) here but it does not work on my system as some users have reported that shell extension does not work for Ubuntu 20.04. I could not figure out a way to do this. Is there a solution or workaround for this?

EDIT

Following @Terrance and other answers here, I installed gnome-clocks and then panel world clock (lite). I was able to get multiple clocks on my top bar with corresponding time zones.

[image]

But it does not show me the option to change the time zone to city name. Why is this happening? Any fixes for this? I will very much prefer city names to time zones.

[image]

I am not sure if it has anything to do with panel world clock version but mine is 11.

[image]

Comment: This one is a possibility as it will show under the calendar:  https://askubuntu.com/a/1071064/231142 as well as the answer below it works to put clocks on the bar.  You might get an error with Panel World Clock (Lite) but you just log out and back in after installing it and it works fine.

Comment: Is there a way to get time with names of cities? Because after you have 3 or 4 clocks, it starts becoming confusing which time is where by just looking at top bar.

Comment: Yes.  When you install https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/946/panel-world-clock-lite/ there will be a configure option that will launch the configuration and allow you to select the show the city names you have chosen.

Comment: I was able to install gnome-clocks and then Panel World Clock (Lite) and it shows multiple clocks on top bar. However, when I attempted to configure the extension so that it shows city names next to local times instead of EST, CET etc, it shows options to change only panel location, number of clocks and hide local time. There is no option to have city names next to times. What did I miss?

Comment: Added an answer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the two answers that are here [How to get world clocks to show on the task bar in Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1070718/how-to-get-world-clocks-to-show-on-the-task-bar-in-ubuntu-18-04) will give you the ability to have the clocks on the bar and to set them with the city names instead.

After you get the `gnome-clocks` installed `sudo apt install gnome-clocks` then you visit https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/946/panel-world-clock-lite/ and enable the plugin for the world clock lite.  You will probably need to log out and back in after enabling it if it gives you an error when you enable it.

After you have logged back in, revisit https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/946/panel-world-clock-lite/ and click on the configure button:

[image]

The Panel World Clock Lite configuration will launch.  Enable location instead of time zone in panel:

[image]

Enjoy the city names instead of time zone name:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @Terrance. But I am not getting the option the change time zones to city names. I modified my question to add details and show the configuration options panel world clock (lite) is showing me. Any solutions and what might be causing this?

Comment: @VKahn That might have something to do with 20.04.  I am running 22.04.  I can try spinning up a 20.04 VM and see if I can get it working.

Comment: @VKahn Unfortunately, I cannot see any answer on how to enable the city names in the extension.  I even downloaded an extension manually for 3.38, but it didn't want to enable that part for Ubuntu 20.04.  Sorry I cannot be more help than that.

Comment: You were great @Terrance. Thanks a lot of all you could share with me.

Comment: @VKahn I did notice with 20.04 that you can click on the time in the bar and it shows you the city that you chose.  It does kind of suck that it doesn't let you show the city names for first glance though.  Looks like for later releases of GNOME that they added the ability to show city names, but those versions will crash in 20.04 if installed.

Comment: Today, I upgraded my system to Ubuntu 22.04.01 LTS and was able to get all the world clocks on my top bar with respective city names. Thanks again, @Terrance.